# Why does my fetchedResultsController.ObjectAtIndexPath return NSFetchRequestResult instead of an object?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I thought this would be a straight forward thing to do but for some unknown reason, I can't access the properties of the object at a given `indexPath`.

I'm trying to create my app using MVVM as much as possible (still using Swift 2.3) so my `UITableViewController` is backed by a view model called `FormulasViewModelFromLiftEvent`. The view model is initialized with a `fetchedResultsController` like so:

```
struct FormulasViewModelFromLiftEvent {
    var modelLiftEvent: LiftEventProtocol
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController
    let dataManager = CoreDataHelper()

    init(withLiftEvent liftEventModel: LiftEventProtocol) {
        self.modelLiftEvent = liftEventModel

        let moc = modelLiftEvent.context
        fetchedResultsController = dataManager.fetchSelectableFormulas(moc)
    }
}
```

The results are a collection of Formula objects.

Back in my `UITableViewController`, I have this extension in which I'm putting the required table view methods. I can access the `fetchResultsController` of the view model within the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods with no problems. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I want to populate the cell with the formula name property but I can't access any of the properties of the `objectAtIndexPath`:

```
extension FormulasViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sections = viewModel.fetchedResultsController.sections else { return 0 }
    return sections.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let section = viewModel.fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else { return 0 }
    return section.numberOfObjects
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellViewModel: SelectionsRepresentable

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("formulasCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let formula = viewModel.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let formulaName = formula.    <-- None of the Formula properties are available

        cellViewModel = FormulaSelectionViewModel(defaultFormulaName: formulaName)

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellViewModel.text
        cell.accessoryType = cellViewModel.accessoryType

        return cell
      }
}
```

According to the documentation, `let formula = viewModel.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)` should return the Formula *object* at the given index path in the fetch results. But `formula` thinks it's an `NSFetchRequestResult` and so of course I can't access any Formula properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSFetchRequestResult` is the protocol `NSManagedObject`, `NSDictionary`, `NSManagedObjectID` and `NSNumber` conform to. You need to type cast the object:

```
let formula = viewModel.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Formula
```

Comment: Thanks, @vadian. I looked at some tutorials I have and this works without casting, however, they're in Swift 3. Is this a difference between Swift 2.3 and 3?

Comment: In Swift 3 `NSFetchedResultsController` is generic. So you can initialize the controller passing the static type.